# Bayes network clarification

Tags: conditional-statements, probability, bayesian-networks

I am trying to learn Bayes Network and I have a problem that I would like some clarification on.

Given the table

[CPT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMOSY.png)

What would the  p(Aggression=high|Anger=Partly,Hostility=Yes) be? My answer is 0.5.

My thought process is that Anger and Hostility are dependent, so according to the info given, the probability of partly anger and yes hostility is 0.5.

Aggression is independent of the two, so it would just be P(aggression)*0.5= 0.5.

Would this be a correct assumption?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: My value for  `p(Aggression=high|Anger=Partly,Hostility=Yes)` is  `100%.`

If Aggression were indepent of  Hostility and Anger, it would not matter what evidence you have.
So p(Aggression) was the maximum of the 3 values p(Agg=low), p(Agg=high), p(Agg=veryhigh).

However the 3*9 table implies p(Agg) = p(Hos, Ang) and it is *not* independent.

I have tried to model your [CPT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMOSY.png) (upper table) with the free software "Samiam".
I doing so I've entered the values from the CPT for the Aggression node  in Samiam.
For the priors: I am assuming someone who is in Anger 5% of the time, partly angry 15% of the time, and 80% not angry; and hostile 10%  of the time, partly hostile 30% or not hostile 60% of the time.

See screenshots:
[image: prepopulated values]

Table values for Aggression Node:
[image]

With Observed Evidence - Value of Aggression=High goes up to 100%:
[image]

I've also attached the samiam file:

```
net
{
    propagationenginegenerator1791944048146838126L = "edu.ucla.belief.approx.BeliefPropagationSettings@20ece334";
    recoveryenginegenerator6944530267470113528l = "edu.ucla.util.SettingsImpl@49f77e1b";
    node_size = (130.0 55.0);
    huginenginegenerator3061656038650325130L = "edu.ucla.belief.inference.JoinTreeSettings@71a1d859";
}

node Aggression
{
    states = ("Low" "High" "VeryHigh" );
    position = (268 -263);
    diagnosistype = "AUXILIARY";
    DSLxSUBMODEL = "Root Submodel";
    ismapvariable = "false";
    ID = "variable2";
    label = "Aggression";
    DSLxEXTRA_DEFINITIONxDIAGNOSIS_TYPE = "AUXILIARY";
    excludepolicy = "include whole CPT";
}
node Anger
{
    states = ("no" "partly" "yes" );
    position = (118 -48);
    diagnosistype = "AUXILIARY";
    DSLxSUBMODEL = "Root Submodel";
    ismapvariable = "false";
    ID = "variable0";
    label = "Anger";
    DSLxEXTRA_DEFINITIONxDIAGNOSIS_TYPE = "AUXILIARY";
    excludepolicy = "include whole CPT";
}
node Hostility
{
    states = ("No" "Partly" "Yes" );
    position = (351 -46);
    diagnosistype = "AUXILIARY";
    DSLxSUBMODEL = "Root Submodel";
    ismapvariable = "false";
    ID = "variable1";
    label = "Hostility";
    DSLxEXTRA_DEFINITIONxDIAGNOSIS_TYPE = "AUXILIARY";
    excludepolicy = "include whole CPT";
}
potential ( Aggression | Anger Hostility )
{
    data = (((  1.0 0.0 0.0 )
        (   0.5 0.5 0.0 )
        (   0.5 0.0 0.5 ))
        ((  0.5 0.5 0.0 )
        (   0.5 0.5 0.0 )
        (   0.0 1.0 0.0 ))
        ((  0.5 0.0 0.5 )
        (   0.0 0.5 0.5 )
        (   0.0 0.0 1.0 )));
}
potential ( Anger | )
{
    data = (    0.8 0.15    0.05    );
}
potential ( Hostility | )
{
    data = (    0.6 0.3 0.1 );
}
```